# Is it possible to get this information with one query?

Tags: database, database-design

Lets say I am coding a simple forum and have tables: 'user', 'forum', 'forum_subscribers', and 'posts'. 'groups', 'posts' and 'forum_subscribers' reference 'user' as a foreign key.

I want to create a view called 'user_profile' that includes

- the count of the number of forums a user has subscribed to,
- the number of posts they posted in forum_x, and
- the total number of posts  in all forums (you can think of a group as a forum or category).

How can I do this using the count() function?

Comment: can you explain this `the number of posts they posted in forum_x`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do much better than 3 unions (maybe the last 2 can be combined with `COUNT DISTINCT`). I made a lot of assumptions about your table structure below, but I assume it should be easy enough to translate this to your structure.

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT user.id, CAST(posts.forum_id AS VARCHAR(20)) AS forum_id, COUNT(posts.id)
FROM user
  JOIN posts ON user.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY user.id, posts.forum_id
    UNION
SELECT user.id, 'All forums', COUNT(posts.id)
FROM user
  JOIN posts ON user.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY user.id
    UNION
SELECT user.id, 'Subscription count', COUNT(fs.forum_id)
FROM user
  JOIN forum_subscribers fs ON user.id = fs.user_id
GROUP BY user.id
```